# echo the value of a checkbox

Tags: php, html

I'm just trying to make sure the value of my checkbox is set to the ID

```
 <td align="center" ><input type="checkbox" name="bob[]" value="<?php echo $row_contactlist['contact_id']; ?>"></td>
      <td align="center" ><p><?php echo $row_contactlist['contact_id'];?></p></td>
      <td align="center" ><p><?php echo $_POST['bob']; ?></p></td>
```

The `$_POST['bob']` does not return anything, but the echo `$row_contactlist` works just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Has your form been submitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things :

- First of all, when `$_POST` will only contain data when the form has been submitted *(not when it's displayed for the first time)*
- Then, you name your checkbox `bob[]`

  - This means PHP will receive an array for `bob`
  - If you use `var_dump($_POST)`, you'll see how `$_POST['bob']` looks like : an array -- which can contain several values, depending on the number of checkboxes you have.

Answer (score 3):

The data will appear only if:

- The form has been submitted
- The checkbox is checked

You also need to reference it correctly. PHP will convert form controls with a name ending in `[]` into an array, so you need to access it as an array.

- `$_POST['bob'][0]`

Comment: Last but not least, use `htmlspecialchars()` to inject user data into your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of each check box, instead of typing everything as `$_POST['bob'][0]`, you can put it inside loop.